# SQL Query works without WHERE, but once I add WHERE statement, it is not running properly

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

There is an SQL query I am writing which executes fine when written as below, but it updates all rows.

```
mysqli_query($connection, 'UPDATE users SET hashed_pass = ' . mysql_escape($newpassword).'');
```

However, as soon as I attempt to add some logic to it by adding a WHERE statement, I don't get any errors but it is not updating the password for the intended user. I want the statement to update, in this case, user 569 (which is what $user_id is equal to).

```
mysqli_query($connection, 'UPDATE users SET hashed_pass = ' . mysql_escape($newpassword).' WHERE user_id ='.mysql_escape($user_id).'');
```

The mysql_escape function just strips slashes and escapes the variable so I know that is not the cause.  I also made sure that the table does in fact have the user_id column and the variable $user_id is 569, which matches the user I want to update. After I run the command I don't get any errors and I have an echo statement under the query to confirm that it ran.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Update:
As everyone suggested I, converted my code to a prepared statement and it is now working.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,  "UPDATE users SET hashed_pass = ? WHERE user_id = ?");                             
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $newpassword, $user_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: "what I am doing wrong".  That's easy.  You are munging query strings with literal values when you should be using parameters.

Comment: what happens if you alter the code to `mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users SET hashed_pass = '" . mysql_escape($newpassword)."' WHERE user_id ='".mysql_escape($user_id)."'");`  Also, note that concatenation like this is frowned upon for security purposes.

Comment: You're mixing APIs. You can't use mysql_* functions with mysqli. Skip the escape string and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies, I tried your solution @TheMouseMaster and unfortunately it didn't work, I will revise the code to be a prepared statement as Gordon and aynber suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements would be the first step. [PHP mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "UPDATE users SET hashed_pass = ?")

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $citynewpassword);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used a prepared statement and it is working now!